# Cucumber Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.io.ResourceLoader

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I am facing an error whenever I run the cucumber test by Junit. Here is the following Exception. Any help will be awesome

**NOTE:**

**THERE IS NO ERROR IN THE PROJECT**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/io/ResourceLoader
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2708)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1659)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.hasConstructor(Reflections.java:53)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:29)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:96)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:63)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:74)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.io.ResourceLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 28 more
```

Here is how my POM.xml looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Cucumber</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

           <!-- Cucumber -->   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RC5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the image of my project structure:
[image]

And here is my RunIT.Java Class

```
package com.Cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        tags={"@mysingle"},
        features = {"."})
public class RunIT {

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the cucumber-core library.

Try adding the following to your dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, you appear to be mixing and matching versions.  Try using the same version for all the cucumber-* libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run Cucumber in java, and you haven't loaded the Cucumber-java dependency? How's your Cucumber supposed to execute?

Here are the minimum dependencies needed to get your Cucumber up & running:

-Cucumber-java (1.2.2) 
   -Cucumber-junit (1.2.2)
   -Cucumber-picocontainer (1.2.2)
   -junit (4.12)

Maven manages the rest of the dependencies. Make sure you have the latest dependencies, and that you are not mixing and matching versions (for example, I've used all 1.2.2 version)

Edit: Just noticed that your Cucumber-java is at the bottom of the pom.xml. It's a good practice to order your dependencies....all cucumber dependencies go together, one after another.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all your cucumber-* jars have the same version, Try this thing - It should resolve your issue.